# Using ReadDirectoryChangesW to read changes to the folder itself (WINDOWS)

Tags: windows, winapi, event-handling, filesystems, msdn

**From the doc** (ReadDirectoryChangesW):

"Retrieves information that describes the changes within the specified directory. The function does not report changes to the specified directory itself."

**My question is**: What do I use to report changes to the specified directory itself?

I want to be able to capture changes not only to things and sub-things in the folder itself but also to detect for example, when the folder itself has been deleted.

**One strategy** would be to actually monitor for changes on the parent of the folder I'm really interested in and then use that to generate an event when the folder I'm interested in is deleted. This works but has the potential to generate thousands of 'uninteresting' events.

**A second strategy** is to have a recursive monitor for stuff under the folder I'm actually interested in and then a non-recursive monitor on it'a parent. The non-recursive monitor would then be able to tell me when the real folder of interest is deleted.

The latter, second strategy, generates fewer events and is the strategy I would like to use. BUT: It doesn't work 'in process'. That is, if I start to monitor the folder of interest recursively (HANDLE A), and it's parent non-recursively (HANDLE B) and then in the same process, I try and delete the folder of interest, no removal event is generated for it (even though I verify from a console that the thing no longer exists). My suspicion is that this is due to HANDLE A on the folder still being open, and even though I have included the "FILE_SHARE_DELETE" flag in the call to CreateFileW that gave me HANDLE A, it simply can't work.

Note that 'Out of process', i.e. when I delete the folder from within a completely separate process, the above strategy does work.

**So, what are my options?**

Many thanks,

Ben.

Comment: You could try using `SHChangeNotifyRegister` to request notifications from the shell when the parent folder is deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jonathan. Looking in to!

Comment: Thanks Hans. That isn't always true: it can be deleted, but only if done so out of process (and if FILE_SHARE_DELETE has been specified when calling CreateFile on the folder); I would like to also be able to delete in process. Note, I would like to avoid monitoring the parent for reasons explained in my original posting. Thanks for the clarification regarding Jonathan's recommendation.

Comment: @HansPassant  believe it or not, you can rename, delete, and restore the directory being monitored by **ReadDirectoryChangesW**. And while Cygwin for example cannot write into the deleted directory, the underlying directory node still exists. And when restored via the shell, changes within the directory are detected by the same overlapped context. Same is true when the base directory is renamed.